# Variable Not Getting Pulled From config File?

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopify

I'm new to CodeIgniter, but I'm loving it so far!

I'm in the process of porting over the Shopify API to a CodeIgniter library but I'm running into a small issue that I can't figure out for the life me!

I'm getting an undefined variable error, and I feel like it is something very simple that I am missing, but I can't understand why it isn't working. Here is the relevant code from the custom class:

```
class Shopify
{

public $_api_key;
public $_shared_secret;
//public $_shops_myshopify_domain;



public function __construct ()
{
    $this->_assign_libraries();

    $this->_api_key                     = $this->config->item('api_key', 'shopify');
    $this->_shared_secret               = $this->config->item('shared_secret', 'shopify');
    //$this->_shops_myshopify_domain        =$this->config->item('shops_myshopify_domain', 'bitauth');
}

public function shopify_app_install_url($shop_domain)
{
    return "http://$shop_domain/admin/api/auth?api_key=$_api_key";
}
 public function _assign_libraries()
 {
    if($CI =& get_instance())
    {
        $this->load     = $CI->load;
        $this->config   = $CI->config;

        $this->load->config('shopify', TRUE);

        return;
    }
 }[/code]
```

Here is the code from the config file I created:

```
/**
* Your shared secret
*/
$config['shared_secret'] = 'changed for posting on forum';

/**
* Your Shopify API key
*/
$config['api_key'] = 'changed for posting on forum';
```

And here is the relevant code in the controller:

```
    Class shopifyPermission extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load the Shopify API library
        $this->load->library('shopify.php');
        // Require url helper to perform the header redirect
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    function index() {
        //require 'shopify.php';

        $shop_domain = "changed.myshopify.com";

        $url = $this->shopify->shopify_app_install_url($shop_domain);

        //redirect($url);

         $data['url'] = $url;

         $this->load->view('shopifyPermission_view', $data);
    }

}
```

The error that I get is as follows:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: _api_key

Filename: libraries/Shopify.php

Line Number: 34

So apparently the api key is not getting pulled from the config file even though I have a valid api key? When I do an echo it shows me the whole URL but the API key is not there. I am at a loss as to what to do and would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten to add `$this` in your `shopify_app_install_url()`

```
public function shopify_app_install_url($shop_domain)
{
    return "http://$shop_domain/admin/api/auth?api_key={$this->_api_key}";
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what the problem was. Thanks so much for your help.